# How to retrieve a route template variable given the HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, versioning, asp.net-web-api

I have two API controllers located in two different folders which has GetEvents() action:

```
V1
  EventsController

V2
  EventsController
```

I'd like to be able to access the controllers using:

```
 api/v1/events and api/v2/events
```

my route template looks like this

```
api/v{version}/{controller}
```

private static string GetRequestVersion(HttpRequestMessage request)
 {

// how to find the {version} value from url?

}

I've written a code using REGEX which works fine:

```
 private static string ExtractVersionFromUrl(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            Match match = Regex.Match(request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery, @"/v(?<version>\d+)/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            return match.Success ? match.Groups["version"].Value : null;
        }
```

What's the standard approach to retreive such data from uri?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
Request.GetRouteData().Values["version"];
```

`GetRouteData` is an extension method and is available in the namespace `System.Net.Http`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hazarding a guess regarding the return value. Another way to do this is simply define it as a parameter in your method in the controller like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Event> GetEvents(string version, HttpRequestMessage request) {
...
}
```

I just figured this out myself. Web API is just beautiful!